# How to send a mail alert on field value change in Table with both value old one and changed on

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Table "Customer" which contain a Field "CreditLimit",
Now I want a Mail alert on change of this filed with both value old credit limit value and New credit limit value.

Is its possible without trigger??
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 0):

The best way to sending mails if any table row value is changed is to apply a trigger.
You need to be more precise with your requirement as to why you want it without trigger.